# How to calculate code coverage in Hudson using emma for a multi-module maven project but only run tests once

Tags: java, maven-2, emma

We have several multi-module projects which I want to run emma against, but I don't want the tests to be run twice, because this results in misleading statistics on the Hudson project home page as unit tests are counted twice.

For a single module project, we can ommit the install goal and just use clean emma:emma to run the tests once, is there any way we can test only using emma instrumented byte code and then build & install the project artifacts without running the tests a second time?  Using -Dmaven.tests.skip=true causes emma to fail.

For a full release (i.e. mvn release:perform) the tests should be run un-instrumented.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider the following [article](http://www.sonarsource.org/measure-code-coverage-by-integration-tests-with-sonar/) to answer "how to calculate.." code coverage. The coverage would then not be visible in Hudson but in sonar. This is not exactly what you are looking for, but [sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Install+Sonar) is worth an evaluation. (Installation is really a breeze)

I would use a profile to activate the test configuration with emma, and that by default the project is built and installed without running tests.