# Cobertura in Jenkins always gets 0% coverage

Tags: android, jenkins, cobertura

Some facts:

1. I'm using jenkins with Cobertura.
2. I have a multi-module Android project, one module is for testing and the other is the actual bl.
3. I'm using jdk 1.6.22.
4. I'm running clean pmd:pmd package cobertura:cobertura
5. My pom file for the testing module contains:

```
  ...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.realw</groupId>
    <artifactId>widget</artifactId>
    <type>apk</type>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version'>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.realw</groupId>
    <artifactId>widget</artifactId>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency></pre>
...
<build>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <instrumentation>
            <ignores>
                <ignore>com.realw.bl.test.*</ignore>
            </ignores>
        </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I've followed the various tutorials and read the posts here, no luck.

I'm sure I'm missing something in the configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717846/how-do-i-get-emma-or-cobertura-with-maven-to-report-coverage-on-source-code-in

Comment: At the end I used emma, seems to work.